# Inject multiline environment variable into BOSH deployment property

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb, cf-bosh

Assuming I have a BOSH deployment

---

```
name: some-name
director_uuid: some-uuid
releases:  
compilation:
 ....
resource_pools:
 ...
networks:
 ...
jobs:
 - name: deployment_name
  instances: 1
  templates:

  resource_pool: ...
  networks: ..
  my_prop: "<%= ENV['MY_ENV_VAR'] %>"
```

How to inject multiline MY_ENV_VAR value so the formatting (line breaks) are rendered properly in target deployment  ?

The release consuming the my_prop uses it under the hood like this

```
 <%= p('my_prop') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do use the YAML `literal_block` feature `|` [1]

```
name: some-name
director_uuid: some-uuid
releases:  
compilation:
 ....
resource_pools:
 ...
networks:
 ...
jobs:
 - name: deployment_name
  instances: 1
  templates:

  resource_pool: ...
  networks: ..
  my_prop: |
      "<%= ENV['MY_ENV_VAR'] %>"
```

[1] https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/